# Install Ubuntu 14 alongside Fedora 21

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, fedora

Im trying to install Ubuntu 14. I have installed Fedora 21. When the installer asks to replace fedora or do something else, I choose do something else, then I get to the following sreen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKlyn.png

When I open gparted from the ubuntu live cd, I see a warning saying "/dev/sdb contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table. However it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.", and then gparted opens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcEM9.png

I don't understand about partitioning, could you tell me how to have both ubuntu and fedora installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open gparted as well as something else in the installer

I'm rusty but if you can locate the partition that Fedora is installed on you can change the slider to the middle, this will split the volume giving us free space for Ubuntu.

What about the other small partitions? well like windows for example; it needs a extra partition for stuff. so ignore those as there for fedora.

okay down to business.

select free space and click add

- Logical
  *Beginning
  *Size = twice your RAM
  -example: you have 8 gigs of ram so input 16000
  *use as swap area

Click on free space again.

*Size = 15000 (15 gigs)
*Beginning 
*Use as ext3
*Mount point = /

Click free space

*Use remaining space
*Beginning
*ext3
*Mount point = /

click install

what we did was partition Linux a manual way, now you can get lazy if you have more than 2 operating systems and just installing to a root (/) partition.

you can Google Nixxi Pixxel does Linux on installing Ubuntu on manual

I really hope this helps. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

From the images you provided it clear that the Fedora has been installed on all the available memory (500GB)on HDD so you have following option.

- Create free space from fedora as separate drive i.e. sda3 and install ubuntu on it as per ubuntu installation manual.
- Install virtual machine in fedora and install ubuntu on it if it works in your case.
- Re-install fedora not on complete space have at-least 40GB free memory and install ubuntu on it.

  For the Ubuntu Portioning refer to the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

For Fedora partitioning refer to the links:

- Partition [setup fedora](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/s1-diskpartitioning-x86.html)
- Manual Partition [Fedora setup](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/21/html/Installation_Guide/sect-installation-gui-manual-partitioning.html)